# Do static members enter objects?

Tags: java, oop, object, static

This is certainly an elementary question, but I must ask to clarify an issue of mine. If a class member is made **static**, it may be accessed without instantiation, with a syntax like *class.member*. When an object is created, does it receive the static member, and can that value be changed? Since a static member does not need objects, is it the same for any object? (ie changed in one, changed in the other).

Basically, how are static members implemented in objects, and how do they change?
and can they only be manipulated with static methods?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can technically change a static member with an instance like this:

```
SomeClass c = new SomeClass();
c.someStaticMember = 5;
```

However, that will create a warning, which it should. The correct way would be to do this:

```
SomeClass.someStaticMember = 5;
```

> Since a static member does not need objects, is it the same for any object? (ie changed in one, changed in the other).

Again, technically yes, since you *can* do this:

```
System.out.println(c.someStaticMember);
```

That is incorrect though and will give you a warning; the correct way is:

```
System.out.println(SomeClass.someStaticMember);
```

Answer (score 2):

> Do static members enter objects?

No. They are held in a different place, in fact in the class itself.

> When an object is created, does it receive the static member

No.

> and can that value be changed?

Yes, unless it's final, but that change affects the single static variable that is seen by all the instances.

> Since a static member does not need objects, is it the same for any object? (ie changed in one, changed in the other).

Yes.

> Basically, how are static members implemented in objects

They aren't. They are implemented in the class.

> and how do they change?

When and if you change them.

> and can they only be manipulated with static methods?

No, a static variable can be manipulated by any method that has access to it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's Look at this.

First of all, remember that static methods (and for that matter static variables) associated with the `Class` not with any particular instance. Static methods exists even if you don't create any instances.

To access a static method you do this:

```
ClassName.staticMethodName(args)
```

Although, Java also allows you to access static variables using instance (object), however this is discouraged as it creates confusion as to whether the method is static or not.

```
objectName.staticMethodName(args)
```

Now to your questions:

> > When an object is created, does it receive the static member, and can that value be changed?

Static members exists with the defining Class not with any object. If the Static member is a mutable variable, then you can certainly change it's value. Everyone (Class's own object, any other objects, any other static methods) will then see that same value.

> > Since a static member does not need objects, is it the same for any object? (ie changed in one, changed in the other).

Yes. Note though, at the expense of repeating myself, that static members are associated with the Class, not the object.

> > Basically, how are static members implemented in objects, and how do they change? and can they only be manipulated with static methods?

Oh man, this is getting tiring :) Static members are NOT implemented in object. They can be manipulated from other static and non-static method (basically from anywhere provided permissions are there). However, static members cannot see any instance variables unless they define that instance.

Answer (score 1):

> When an object is created, does it receive the static member, and can that value be changed?

yes of course you can change the value of a static member using an object but it's better if you you change it using the class name.

> Since a static member does not need objects, is it the same for any object?

yes again, a static member means that this member is the same in all instances created of this class and can be accessed through any object or through the class name.

> how do they change?

there is 2 ways to change the value of a static member:

```
public static int x = 5;
Object.x = 10;
Class.x = 20
```

and both methods to change the static member value are correct, however the first method will give you a warning, the second will not.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Doorknob's answer, specifically in response to:

> and can they only be manipulated with static methods

You are able to access and change static members in various ways as shown below:

```
public class Foo {

    public static String BAR = "BAR!!";

    public static void changeBAR() {
        BAR = "BAZ!";
    }

    public void instanceMethod() {
        // some code
        BAR = "CHANGED AGAIN!";
        // some code
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo f = new Foo();
        System.out.println(Foo.BAR);

        Foo.changeBAR();
        System.out.println(Foo.BAR);

        f.instanceMethod();
        System.out.println(Foo.BAR);

        Foo.BAR = "WHATS HAPPENING";
        System.out.println(Foo.BAR);
    }
}
```

Will result in:

```
BAR!!
BAZ!
CHANGED AGAIN!
WHATS HAPPENING
```